# VB.net adding and subtracting using buttons while changing the value of the total answer

Tags: vb.net

This is an example of a small part of my program. I seem to know the problem, I think the problem is that the two button sub are not communicating with each other. Each button don't know if the value was change by another button. For example if the value of the total is 1 and I click the subtract button the value will change into 0, which is right. But if I add again the value becomes 2, which is wrong. The right answer should be 1. The total in add button don't know that the subtract button change it value. Please help me with this problem.

```
Dim total As Integer = 0

Public Sub addbutton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addbutton.Click
    total += 1
    labeltotal.Text = total
End Sub
Public Sub subtractbutton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles subtractbutton.Click
    total -= 1
    labeltotal.Text = total
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of application is this? web, console,etc...Also, post the code for the button definitions.

Comment: You could set the value of total = to your textbox. IE total = labeltotal.Text

Comment: If `total` is indeed, as it currently seems, a class-level variable then this should work.

Comment: @codeMonger123 I did but in reverse labeltotal.Text = total

Comment: Is `total` declared in the same class (i.e. form) as the buttons, or in a `Module`? If the former, then there must be something else to it. Is there any more code you can share? -- Also try creating a new project and doing it there.

Comment: @RickS this is a console what do you mean by button definitions?

Comment: @VisualVincent yes the total is declared in the same class (i.e. form) as the buttons, I don't know what else to share because I just make this simple code to be an example of my problem. What kind of code you need for me to help you, for you to help me?

Comment: Surely this can't be a Console Application? You must mean WinForms? -- By button definitions he meant the button-related code that's in the `Form.Designer.vb` file.

Comment: try labeltotal.text = Integer.Parse(labeltotal.text)+1

Comment: I was asking for more code if you had any, because I thought there might be something else changing the variable... Could you give us _**all**_ the code within your form and the `.Designer.vb` file if it's not too long?

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes it is too long my program is about pre-enrollment system. Check this [Screenshot1](http://imgur.com/a/jW1Rz) and [Screenshot2](http://imgur.com/a/JICXE) . all variables in the picture was declared in the same form. Hope this help, thanks.

Comment: @VisualVincent my goal is to add subjects and it will go to subject loads listbox then I have the option to remove it. The accumulated units should be deducted equal to the units remove.

Comment: Try to reproduce a minor version of it in a new project and post that code here if you experience the same problem. If not, then you would have to give us a more detailed example of the input/output to the code in the screenshots. We need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with.

Comment: Is it the `addunits` and `subunits` variables you're referring to? If so you seem to have forgotten the addition/subtraction operators.

Comment: Yes I see that from your screenshot, but isn't there supposed to be an addition/subtraction operator there as well? What do you do with those variables?

Comment: @VisualVincent Please check again I edited it, my bad.

Comment: @VisualVincent oops my bad I was trying the suggested answer that was deleted. The code was `subunits = Convert.ToInt32(LBunits.SelectedItem)`
 `accunits = accunits - subunits` 
`lblAccUnits.Text = accunits` the accunits variable has been declare same as the subunits and addunits. the code in add units is same like subunits just change the sign to positive

Comment: Then it should add/subtract with whatever `addunits` or `subunits` are. I can't see any problems with it. Best advice: Place a breakpoint on the `accunits` line and inspect the variables.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you so much for really trying hard to help. Best of luck to you.

Comment: No problem, though how big is this exactly? I'd like to help you solve it so do you think you could e-mail the project to me? You'll find my address here: http://support.mydoomsite.com/.

Comment: @VisualVincent Okay thanks I will try to email you my program.

Comment: Hi, is the variable total a part of a class? Maybe you're recreating the class everytime before pressing the button. Otherwise total could be set as public variable. Or you need to ensure not recreating the class.

Comment: @pLurchi : It's a variable in the same form, he stated so earlier.

Comment: @ameer : I can't help but notice that I haven't received anything from you :). I'll just need this specific form of yours (its related `.vb`, `.Designer.vb` and `.resx` files) if it's enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VisualVincent I can't send two of these files through gmail because they don't allow executable files to be sent. Any advice on where to send these files?

Comment: You should be able to send the `.vb`-files in compressed (zipped) format... If not, just copy-paste them to http://pastebin.com/ and send the links.